# Nodejs - Sending JWT token in headers with res.redirect();

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I am using jsonwebtoken package.i not understanding how to send token with res.redirect();

```
app.post("/login",(req,res) => {

var newUser = new User(req.body);
newUser.save().then((result) => {
    return newUser.generateAuthToken();
}).then((token) => {
    if(!token) {
        return Promise.reject();
    }
    res.header("x-auth",token).redirect("/main");
  }).catch((err) => res.send("err"));
});
```

Help me please

Comment: And the problem is .. ?

Comment: i am not getting header at "/main"

Comment: How about `res.set(‘x-auth’, token); res.redirect(‘/main’);`? Have you tried with a `cookie`?